# Sublime Text - Convert text to JSON format

Tags: regex, sublimetext

I have a text file that looks similar to this:

```
Reference: 10001
Title: This is a text file
Description: A text file containing some simple strings
<0x0c>
Reference: 10002
Title: This is an xml file
Description: An xml file containing some generic data
<0x0c>
```

Basically, where I see a pattern like `<word>:` Id like to insert `"` before and after the `<word>`, then id like to insert `"` before and after the value followed by a `,` like this:

```
"Reference" : "10001",
```

So far I can get the whole line using the following Regex:

```
^.*(Reference:|Title:).*$
```

But i'm wondering if there is a better way to select only the text I need and then make the required transformation.

Comment: Try `^(\w+)(:\s*)(.*)` => `"$1"$2"$3",`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Wow, thats pretty good. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to match the whole line but only the text, you could use 3 capturing groups and make use of word boundaries `\b`:

```
\b(Reference|Title)(:\s*)(\d+)\b
```

- `\b(Reference|Title)` Word boundary, capture in group 1 either Reference or Title
- `(:\s*)` Capture in group 2 a colon and 0+ whitespace chars
- `(\d+)\b` Capture in group 3 1+ digits followed by a word boundary

In the replacement use the 3 capturing groups and surround the first and the third with double quotes:

```
"$1"$2"$3"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ihS6Rm/1)

Comment: Thank you, this is a great way to do it. That regex tester is really useful appreciate the link.

Comment: I have one more question, can this also search for lines that have empty values? e.g. `TestLine: `

Comment: Then you could remove the word boundary at the end and repeat the digits 0+ times like https://regex101.com/r/ihS6Rm/2

Comment: Excellent, really well done, although it looks like there is a tiny bug in your demo. Have a look at the Title/Description fields.